# WooCommerce cart total incorrect after applying coupon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

i am using WooCommerce Version 3.5.6, after applying 20% discount coupon to one of the product the total amount is showing 1 Rs less than the actual amount

(eg.) Product price is 3299 on which i am applying a 20% discount coupon which should be 660 and the total amount after discount should be 2639, instead it is showing total as 2638,refer enclosed attachment for more[image] details

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this problem  by downgrading woocommerce from 3.5.6 to 3.5.1.